# $\tau$-admissible lift

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, symmetric-spaces

I've been asked to take on a peer-review task which has to be completed in a short time, obviously details have to remain confidential, I need to work out what ``$\tau$-admissible lift" means if $\tau$ is a unitary representation of a closed subgroup $M$ of a Lie group $G$, and you're sort of considering $\Gamma \setminus G / K$, where $K$ is maximal compact subgroup of $G$ and $\Gamma$ is discrete torsion-free co-compact subgroup of isometry group of $G/K$. No definition given, and the citation is to a textbook which doesn't exist anywhere on the internet or on Amazon or at my local library. And it doesn't say a lift of what. Any helpful hints for the right Google search phrases here much appreciated.

EDIT: Cited textbook is ``Selberg zeta and theta functions: A Differential Operator Approach".

Comment: Complete reference:  *Bunke, Ulrich; Olbrich, Martin. Selberg zeta and theta functions. A differential operator approach. Mathematical Research, 83. Akademie-Verlag, Berlin, 1995. 168 pp.*

Comment: Your library might borrow the book from another library.

Comment: You might be able to find the definition using https://books.google.de/books?id=L_ruAAAAMAAJ&dq=Bunke%2C+Ulrich%3B+Olbrich%2C+Martin.+Selberg+zeta+and+theta+functions.+A+differential+operator+approach.+Mathematical+Research%2C+83.+Akademie-Verlag%2C+Berlin%2C+1995.&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=admissible+lift

Comment: Out of curiosity: were you able to get the book and/or find the definition?

Comment: Still struggling, I'm afraid, but someone who has access to an on-line library resource might be able to send me an electronic copy. It seems very hard to get clarification just from Google, and my own local university library is shut. Still, I'll manage. I think probably the editor appreciates that I'm doing my very best under the circumstances.